# Как сымитировать нажатия клавиши Enter в поисковой строке Chrome?

Tags: c#, selenium

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы перейти на страницу Хрома, ввести в поисковик что-нибудь, затем сымитировать нажатие Enter и взять title после перехода
У меня есть вот такой код, но нажатие на Enter не выходит. Это одно из двух решение что я смог найти. Второе прописать в конце вводимой строки \n, но тоже не работает. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать этот момент

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public void SetTitle()
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Hello World");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        String title = driver.Title;
        Console.WriteLine(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: А можете ответить на вопрос: Зачем? Зачем тут целый браузер? Почему не отправить запрос самостоятельно и обработать HTML?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Так поставлена задача для меня